# Position a widget at vertical center

Tags: flutter-layout

I am having a problem to place Email and Mobile TextFields in the center vertically.

I have tried using Center widget, mainAxisAlignment and crossAxisAlignment but to no avail.

```
passwordInputs() => Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: Center(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              _getEmail(),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
              ),
              _getMobileNumber(),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
              ),
              _getSubmit()
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _getEmail() {
 return Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4),
   child: TextField(
   maxLines: 1,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Email*",
  ),
),
);
}

Widget _getMobileNumber() {
return Container(
margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4),
child: TextField(
  maxLines: 1,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "Mobile*",
   ),
  ),
 );
}
```

These widgets are being displayed on the top of the screen. I need them in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that you have to do is add a `shrinkWrap : true` in the listView, like this

```
Center(
    child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: <Widget>[
        _getMobileNumber(),
        _getEmail()
      ],
    ),
  )
```

And you don't need this column.